# Max. and Min. of $a\sin^2 x+b \cos^2 x$

Tags: trigonometry

$f(x)=a\sin^2 x+b \cos^2 x$

It is stated that, pls check [link](http://www.sscexamtutor.com/2014/07/easiest-way-to-find-maximum-and-minimum.html)

If a > b, Maximum value = a and Minimum value = b

If a < b, Maximum value = b and Minimum value = a

How do we find this?

**My attempt:**

$$
f(x)=a\sin^2 x+b \cos^2 x=a\sin^2 x+b (1-\sin^2 x)=a\sin^2 x+b-b\sin^2 x\\=\sin^2 x(a-b)+b
$$
Range of $\sin^2 x:[0,1]$, So it seems like

$f_{max}=1(a-b)+b=a$ and

$f_{min}=0(a-b)+b=b$

is the only possibility. What am I missing here ?

Comment: you are correct! What is the problem?

Comment: try $a<b$ and look at min and max again

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento how do we get the two cases ?

Comment: Assuming $a$ and $b$ are positive.  If $a<b$, then $(a-b)<0$ thus when $\sin^2 x = 1$ it would be a minimal value.

Comment: You found the limits $a$ and $b$. If $a<b$ them $f_{max}=b$

Comment: Is that clear bellow?

Comment: @AlainRemillard ohh thnx... I should consider the whole term $\sin^2 x(a-b)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=(a-b)\sin^2(x)+b$$

Once $0 \le\sin^2(x) \le 1$ the $f(x)$ has limits $a$ and $b$.

If $a<b$ then $f_{max}=b$ and $f_{min}=a$

If $b<a$ then $f_{max}=a$ and $f_{min}=b$